# 1 sql with 2 different sqlconnections using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have 2 different connections located on different sql servers, Source Server and Target Server.
I want to compare a table that exists in both servers and align the Target Server table with the Source Server one.

```
SqlConnection src = (DataBaseConnection.GetSqlConnection());

SqlConnection trg = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.IDCConnectionDEV);

src.Open();
trg.Open();

SqlCommand source = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Source table", src);
SqlCommand traget = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Target Table", trg);

SqlDataReader drsrc = source.ExecuteReader();
SqlDataReader drtrg = traget.ExecuteReader();

DataTable tbl1 = new DataTable();
tbl1.Load(drsrc);

DataTable tbl2 = new DataTable();
tbl2.Load(drtrg);
```

Now my question is how do i run the following query:

```
(select * from Source table) except (select * from Target table)
```

or any other sql query using tables from both connections.

Comment: If the servers can see each other link one server to the other with sp_addlinkedserver then that server can directly query the second server all by itself. (`select * from otherserver.dbname.dbo.sometable`)

Comment: Or read the data as you do, and then use linq to filter your data

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to run SQL statement across the two different data tables, since they are on different connections.

1. You could create a linked server on one server or the other, and then run a query on one server that joined to the other server with SQL.
2. You could perform the join client-side using something other than SQL.

To perform the join client-side, consider using a merge join to minimize client-side memory needs if these tables are large.  This would be adding an `ORDER BY` clause to both `SELECT` statements to sort both of them by the primary key, or some unique key if you don't have a primary key.  You would then loop through one side and compare to the current record of the other using `<`, `>`, and `==` comparisons to check if records were in one or the other.  You could then determine if a record was in the source and not the target, if there was a record in the target but not the source, or if the record existed in both.  Consider using `IDataReader` instead of `DataTable` in this case to prevent having to load both tables in memory if the tables are really large.

Alternatively, you could use a hash join (which is likely how linq would solve it) if the tables are not enormous and you have plenty of RAM client side.  This would be loading the primary/unique key of one side into a `Dictionary` and then testing every record for the other side to see if it is in the `Dictionary`.  Easier to code, and may be faster, but requires more memory usage.  You could use `IDataReader` instead of `DataTable` to save client-side memory, but you will have to have at least one side of the join fully in memory (in the `Dictionary`)

Finally, you could use Linq queries to perform client-side joins in a SQL-like manner.  This will be the smallest amount of code.  You will have to leave it in `DataTable`, and Linq will likely use a `Dictionary` or `Hashset` under the covers, so you will have 3 copies of the tables in memory for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linked Servers (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine) in your  `SqlCommand` and then look at this example for using `LEFT` or a `RIGHT JOIN` to get the difference between two tables, see e.g.: http://www.dofactory.com/sql/right-outer-join